# exchange 2007 supported Operating System?

Tags: windows, exchange, email-server, exchange-2007

I am newcomer to exchange server, i have two setup of exchange server first one is exchange 2007 SP2 64 bit and other one is exchange 2007 SP3 64 bit, i just want to know which OS will be supported by the above two.

PS:Please do mention the full name of the OS along with SP and bit supported.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you set up this old stuff? and why with two different SP?

Comment: `1.` This information is easily found on the Microsoft web site. `2.` Why are you deploying Exchange Server 2007?

Comment: This is not my question answer buddy??

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2007 SP3: Windows Server 2003 SP2, Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2, Windows Server 2008 SP2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1 for client tools: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff728623(v=exchg.150).aspx